# 'Easy' is to 'beginner' as 'medium' is to _________

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I want to display three levels in my game...but I don't know what the text should say.

- easy -> Beginner
- medium -> ?
- hard -> Expert

Basically, I want the form that describes the person playing the game, instead of the game itself. What adjective is best?

I have considered *adept*.

I doubt my users will know what *adept* means. Also, I need something in between expert and beginner. *Adept* falls into the expert category. Is there anything more common that I can use, that has the same impact as the other two words I mentioned?

*Proficient* would work, theoretically, but in day-to-day use, the levels "beginner - proficient - expert" won't sound great.

Comment: Note that adept implies a higher level of proficiency than you intend. It could be used comparably with expert.

Comment: I'd like to closevote as a duplicate of [List of expertise levels from beginner to expert](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83832/), but that has no upvoted or accepted answers. There's also [What are common word sets for describing ranks in a profession?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20025/) and [More than an intermediate but less so than an expert](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20032/), for example.

Comment: you could use "mid-level player".  it's simply a fact that many things in English don't have one specific word.  there are various obscure options like Debutante.  "adept" unfortunately just sounds incredibly silly, like you're a led zeppelin or "Lord of the Rings" nut who does to cosplay conferences.  So, don't do that.  Yes, you can use "intermediate" even though it's a bit weird.  English readers simply realise "there's no word for that other than 'intermediate'" so you can go ahead and use it.

Comment: note, sometimes you see "beginner, expert, pro" ... for the very reason that there's no word for "mid-level player".  Note too that in some cases you can get away with things like "state!" "national!" "international!"

Comment: The french would use "confirmed" which I find quite good, though I don't know how you get a good noun out of that.

Comment: What type of game is it? & if it's fiction-based, do you want an 'in universe' term or an 'out of universe' term?

Comment: Journeyman? It's slightly archaic but still in use to mean someone who can do a high-quality job on simpler tasks but doesn't have the experience and skills needed to handle complex, precise, or large-scale jobs.

Comment: I think I've seen apprentice used in this way

Comment: Games usually use "normal" between easy and hard.

Comment: @ermanen That sort of implies that beginners and experts are abnormal.

Answer (score 38):

I think the correct word is **intermediate**, as @Rathony mentioned. It's also a noun, so *He is an intermediate* is perfectly OK:

> intermediate (noun): one that is in a middle position or state.

([AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=intermediate))

> intermediate *noun* [countable] [plural *intermediates*]
>   a student, **player** etc who **has not yet reached an advanced level**

([Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/intermediate_2))

One classic example is *Minesweeper*:

[image]

@Rathony If you choose to post "intermediate" as an answer I will happily delete mine or edit it to suggest other alternatives.

**UPDATE**: Some EL&U users have challenged the use of *intermediate* as a noun. Some went as far as to say that ["I'm an intermediate"](http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=146791793) have never (sic!) been said.

If you doubt this usage, consider [this entry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/intermediate) from the *Oxford American Dictionary*:

[image]

Comment: For a real world example, go look at the classic game [Minesweeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Minesweeper). It has three levels: Beginner, Intermediate and Expert.

Comment: The example of Minesweeper is an adjective. All three are adjectives here: *beginner difficulty*, *intermediate difficulty*, *advanced difficulty*. I have serious objections with the use of "intermediate" as a noun in this context. As @jackroy mentioned, "intermediate" as a noun usually means "go-between" or "arbiter". You need a better citation.

Comment: @Era- I'd tend to use *intermediary* as a noun for go-between.

Comment: @Era What are the grounds of your objections to the use of "intermediate" as a noun? Most authoritative dictionaries list it. With examples. You might not use it personally, but that's your choice. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Seeing it in the example makes a lot more sense. I ha e accepted your answer, but do you mind providing a few more words that I can use besides for _intermediate_? I am just trying to get as many options as I can, so I can pick the one that feels best. Again, thanks for the word. Let me know :-) PS: sorry for any typos, I am using the stack exchange app.

Comment: PS: sorry for any typos, I am using the stack exchange app.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Unfortunately, I don't have any other general suggestions at this point that would work as adjectives *and* nouns. Depending on the game, you could perhaps try more specific terms like e.g. ranks in a military game (like *private*, *sergeant*, *colonel*, *general*).

Comment: @A.P. Oh, that's clever! What other ranks do you suggest I can use?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia E.g. Quake 4 uses "Private", "Corporal", "Lieutenant" and "General" (http://quake.wikia.com/wiki/Difficulty).

Comment: Oh, thats cool also! Maybe I'll just go with the beginner, intermediate, expert. But, if you have any more example ranks, please let me know

Answer (score 13):

*Intermediate* is used awkwardly as a noun.

It's most often an adjective as in:

"*...intermediate* English..."

And when it's used as a noun it most instinctually means a *negotiator*. Someone who serves as an *intermediate* between two parties in conflict.

I would recommend the use of ***journeyman***.

It doesn't fit perfectly because of the implication that they will not *necessarily* improve, but in the history of the word in use, many *journeymen* have excelled beyond their perceived abilities and become *champions*, or *experts*.

Comment: I like the "classiness" of "journeyman". I disagree that "intermediate" as an adjective does not "fit" the question requirements -- the implication is "intermediate between beginner and expert". And the more apropos term for the "negotiator" sense is "intermediary" rather than "intermediate".

Comment: +1 I came to suggest journeyman if no one else had.

Comment: Unfortunately if you use " journeyman ", you sound like you're a led zeppelin or "Lord of the Rings" nut who goes along to cosplay conferences. Or worse: someone who goes to " medieval " meets - and has a tent. So, don't do that. Ever.  For any reason.  It's probably worse than "adept" as mentioned above!

Comment: @JoeBlow: some of my best times have been spent camping in a canvas tent and dressing in medieval-style clothing, with 10,000 of my closest friends. So I don't understand your objection on two levels: 1. there's nothing wrong with any of the activities you describe, and 2. I fail to see an association between the term "journeyman" and the activities described.

Comment: Hi Martha, it's completely commonplace to poke fun at medievalists (don't even mention renaissanceistes).  It's a standard cartoon trope, like poking fun at Republicans.  Don't look at me - I chipped in for *Clang* on crowdfunding.  But, like Young Republicans, it's a trope to make fun of.

Comment: BTW, have a merry ye olde christmas!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, except I think that _journeyman_ would sound odd in the context of game...any other suggestions? +1 :-)

Comment: @Ruchir Baronia Understood. Well, I clicked on your profile and found the "Balloon Popper" game, and if that's what it's for I'd go with something that is thematic. I've only just seen it but, I think there's real opportunity to wrap the game in its own clothes by using "invented" categories like: "Floater/Balloonist/Phileas Fogg (see:*Around the World in 80 Days*)" for the "beginner/medium/expert" categories. There are lots of options if that is indeed the game, but if it's another game I'd rather know before ruminating too much...

Comment: By the way, "Balloon Popper" looks excellent as explained. I don't use "smart phones" or whatever - I like my "traditional" computer for what I do - but I read the explanation and I can imagine it in action and it's a good, sound idea. I used to play "astronut" (I think it's called) on my ipod. Reminds me a bit of it...

Answer (score 2):

**Moderate** may fit your needs in terms of difficulty.

> average in amount, intensity, quality, or degree.

You could also change the whole system and use **amateur**, **veteran**, and **professional**. This system is all based on nouns, and can be generally compared with experience and pay.

**Amateur**

> engaging or engaged in without payment; nonprofessional.

**Veteran**

> a person who has had long experience in a particular field.

**Professional**

> a person engaged in a specified activity, especially a sport or branch of the performing arts, as a main paid occupation rather than as a pastime.

Comment: "Moderate" is fine, and highlights the fact that there simply  ***IS NOT*** a noun-like choice, in English. That's just how it is.  As I mention, beginner / expert / pro is the only real solution, which is annoying but it works and everyone understands you do it for exactly that reason.

Comment: @JoeBlow I don't know if I would agree with expert and pro though because the difference between them is difficult to explain in a game-based manner.

Comment: Hi Jord, I agree it is "messy" but it's about the only available solution.  By all means, "moderate" etc is also ok.  Any of the available solutions has problems.

Answer (score 1):

**Adept** (Virtual Villagers Skill Level)

1. Begineer
2. Adept
3. Mater

Answer (score 0):

**Junior** Might fit the bill, it indicates a lower but not necessarily lowest rank.

> [low or lower in rank or status](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/junior).

Answer (score 0):

In context of game difficulty setting where Beginner is easier and Expert is harder, trying to skip answers that have been mentioned before:

Casual, Normal, Average, Skilled, Challenging, Mortal, Padawan, Student, Soldier

Keep in mind in context of a game difficulty setting it isn't perfectly clear if Beginner and Expert are nouns so the intermediate level doesn't have to be a noun either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to explore using the survey design and analysis principles  that have been scientifically accepted for years in the social science field. And they are EASY!

Here's a link to a summary of the principles that may help creating your question and answers and provide you with good data to analyze.[wording for rating scales](http://www.uwex.edu/ces/4h/evaluation/documents/Wordingforratingscales.pdf)

And if you are really keen on the analysis part, I suggest the following paper for displaying and visually analyzing your results. [Plotting Rating Scales](http://www.amstat.org/sections/srms/proceedings/y2011/files/300784_64164.pdf)

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I'm afraid link-only answers don't help, because answers are supposed to be self-contained. Also, it doesn't take much for the links to break. Please summarise the relevant points you want to make, and cite them correctly. This answer may be deleted without that.