# Nouns for people getting better at some activity

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a couple of nouns that describe someone who is noticably improving at some learning activity. If someone is just starting they are a *novice* or a *beginner*; at the end, there are various words (*expert*, *master*, etc.). I am looking for words for someone who is a beginner, but who is markedly getting better, and for someone who is not an expert but is approaching it. I already thought of *improver*. It doesn't seem very satisfactory; neither does *trainee*, which doesn't imply improvement.

Comment: The U3A French group my wife and I attend is called the 'improvers' group'.

Comment: In the old guild system, to be intermediate between novice (apprentice) and master was to be a *[journeyman](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/journeyman).* Unfortunately, its etymology makes the term suggestive of the mere hireling as distinct from the assiduous pursuer of greater competence.

Comment: Perhaps a title like 'Nouns to describe skill level' would be more appropriate for this question.

Comment: I proposed the name "The Learning Curves" for a women's [Real Tennis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_tennis) team I was on, but it didn't catch on.

Answer (score 3):

For the not beginner, not expert, you could use 'intermediate'.

You can get inspiration from this [list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83832/list-of-expertise-levels-from-beginner-to-expert)

Answer (score 3):

Somebody who picks up a skill very quickly is sometimes called a **natural**.

> A person regarded as having an innate gift or talent for a particular task or activity.

For a person who knows the ropes, try **adept**.

> A person who is skilled or proficient at something.

Comment: Both definitions are from Google using the "define:" syntax, which lets you type define: followed by a word or phrase.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard the term "student" used in this context. One might say, "XXX is a student of modern dance." or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

The [Dreyfus model of skill acquisition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreyfus_model_of_skill_acquisition) might be a useful scale.